# Does commenting variables inline with Doxygen come with any penalties?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I see most Doxygen docs for commenting c++ functions looking something akin to

```
/// a description of the function or method followed with comments, like so
/// @return true=success, false=error
/// @param[in] bar blah blah
/// @param[out] baz blah blah
/// @param[out] quux blah blah
/// @param[out] quuux blah blah
/// @param[out] quuuux blah blah
static bool foo_one( int *bar, int *baz, int *quux, int *quuux, int *quuuux );
```

or the xml equivalent (roughly)

```
/// a description of the function or method, followed by
/// <returns>true=success, false=error</returns>
/// <param name=bar>blah blah</param>
/// <param name=baz>blah blah</param>
/// <param name=quux>blah blah</param>
/// <param name=quuux>blah blah</param>
/// <param name=quuuux>blah blah</param>
static bool foo_two( int *bar, int *baz, int *quux, int *quuux, int *quuuux );
```

but I've been mostly commenting my parameters inline, like so

```
/// a description of the function or method, followed by
/// @return true=success, false=error
static bool foo_three(
    int *bar,               ///< [in]  blah blah
    int *baz,               ///< [out] blah blah
    int *quux,              ///< [out] blah blah
    int *quuux,             ///< [out] blah blah
    int *quuuux             ///< [out] blah blah
);
```

All three of these give identical output in the html file (with the exception of the middle one, which doesn't specify in/out).

My question: Are there features of Doxygen, Visual Studio, or any other environment that I won't be able to utilize with my inline approach? I understand that there are personal preferences when writing and reading the comments in code itself and would prefer not to debate those. I'm only interest in know if there are Doxygen or other environment features or formatting I'll be missing out on.

Comment: What do you mean (_penalties_)? Is the documentation rendered well actually? If so, what are you bothering about?

Comment: You may want to ask on one of the [Doxygen Forums](https://www.google.com/search?q=doxygen+forum&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, no offense, but as I asked, are there features of Doxygen, Visual Studio, or any other environment that I won't be able to utilize with my inline approach? I'm happy with the look of the output, but my company is looking to comment huge swaths of legacy code and I don't want to steer them to my technique if XML or other techniques have features I'm not aware of that my approach can't exploit.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys I still don't get what you're after now. Do you use doxygen or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Doxygen itself will work just fine with inline comments.

However, also consider the effect on history recorded by the source code control system (for example, `git`, and `git blame`)

With inline comments, the last person who changed the line is whoever added or changed documentation, which makes it harder to find when / why the *code* itself was changed.

With comments on separate lines, especially if documentation is added after the code, inspecting history to find code changes is easier.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the type of feedback I was looking for. We are git users, so this is a consideration. Any other limitations?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys: If you do NOT inline commenting you will be able to have uncommented parameters or comments for parameters which will be already deleted. I think it is more important to have consistent documentation which is simplified by inline documentation.

Comment: @MarcAlff: I prefer things belong together also be handled together. Your idea that comments will changed without a code change will making it difficult to watch the code history seems not an argument to me. Maybe a matter of taste?